# microsoft sync framework when local cache reach maximum capacity

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

What machanisms or methods, if any, are available to handle the case where the SQL CE has reached it's storage capacity to fully sync an SQL server?

I am just planning ahead so I can't actually try things out, but 4 GB doesn't seem like alot because I might have BLOBs in my database.

Comment: I would think that this is a design limitation; SQL CE / sync framework is only designed to store/sync small or medium amounts of data.  You'd want to use something else or store data outside of the database here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4GB is a lot of local data. Assuming it is important, how do you plan to back it up?
Repeating this over several clients each of which has their own SQL CE means a lot of potential data loss and redundant/repeated data

I'd consider using SQL Server Express *now* because you can upgrade this later

Comment: Users will be expected to upload the data they changed. So that is not a problem (same thing as moving emails from PST to OST then while still transfering to server, outlook crashes! -- just happned 2 days ago)

Comment: @Jake: same answer applies: SQL Server 2008 Express has 10GB limit

Comment: I mainly concern with how to speed up searches if only part of the data is on local cache and the rest on the server.

Comment: @Jake: use the power of a central server then (CPUs, RAM, caching etc). Don't make it too complex yet